# how to trigger click event on child element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following HTML structure:

```
<ul>
  <li>
      1- First Level
  </li>
  <li>
        <ul>
         <li>2 - Second Level</li>
       </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

I have the following jQuery

```
$(document).on('click','li',function(){
  var text = $(this).html();
  alert(text);
});
```

When I click on the `li` having the text `1- First Level`, the click event is triggered.

But when I click on the sub `li` having text `2- Second Level`, the trigger fires on the first li (since it is the parent)..

How can I trigger the click event on each li regardless of its status (parent/child)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`e.stopPropagation()` will be the line you need to add, because any event bound on child bubbles up to the parent node, so result of it is both events occurs in the page.

`e.stopPropagation()` lets you stop the event to bubble up to the parent element in the DOM.

```js
$(document).on('click','li',function(e){
  e.stopPropagation(); // stop the event to bubble up to the parent.
  var text = $(this).html();
  alert(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
      1- First Level
  </li>
  <li>
        <ul>
         <li>2 - Second Level</li>
       </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to stop event propogation using `stopPropagation`:

```
$(document).on('click','li',function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
   var text = $(this).html();
   alert(text);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding stopPropagation() in javascript

```
$(document).on('click','li',function(){
  var text = $(this).html();
  alert(text);
  stopPropagation();
});
```

Here is a fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/wLwccv7y/1/

Edited according to comments

Comment: that would stop the event on all elements.